# empirical distribution from data - python

Tags: python, scipy

[wasserstein_distance function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html) requires that the input data are "**Values observed in the (empirical) distribution**".

My data arrays range between -4 and 8:

```
x = np.array([0.12,-1.29,-3.23,-3.21,-0.13, 1.52, 4.45, 6.45, 5.17, 0.11, 3.48, 5.98, 7.55])
y = np.array([3.54, 2.42,-4.43,-3.76, 0.43, 0.45, 2.56, 7.61, 4.47, 1.36, 2.34, 7.78, 7.13])
```

how can I create an empirical distribution of `x` and `y`?

I tried

```
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF

ecdf_x = ECDF(x)
x_ecdf = ecdf_y.y

ecdf_y = ECDF(y)
y_ecdf = ecdf_y.y

wasserstein_distance(x_ecdf, y_ecdf)
```

Would `x_ecdf` and `y_ecdf` be valid inputs to the function?